# Why does this counter increment correctly on Windows, but not on Android?

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, maui

I started with the Maui template project where you click a button to increase a number stored in the MainPage class.

I removed every element except from a label in the MainPage.xaml. This label I named SpeedLabel so that I can change it from the MainPage class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Metero.MainPage">

<Label
    x:Name="SpeedLabel"
    Text="0"
    SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
    SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
    FontSize="80"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    VerticalOptions="Center" />

</ContentPage>
```

Now in the MainPage C# class (MainPage.xaml.cs) I changed the class to this:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SpeedLabelUpdate();
    }

    private async void SpeedLabelUpdate()
    {
        while (true) {
            count += 1;
            SpeedLabel.Text = count.ToString();
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect this to produce an application with a number that is increasing on the center of the screen. It works as expected on Windows, but not on Android.

On Android the number goes up to 9 as expected, but then it gets reset to 1 and now the delay between the updates are 1000ms instead of 100. If I keep it going it gets reset again when it reaches 9 and now the delay is around 10000ms.

Comment: I suspect the use of async void. Try using async Task instead.

Comment: By simply changing void to Task, the problem still occurs.

Comment: Not so simple. As a general rule, you shouldn't call an `async` method synchronously.

Comment: Why not? How should I then approach this problem?

Comment: I don't see any reason to use async. You can try using a timer instead.

Comment: In 7 hours... xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private async void SpeedLabelUpdate()
{
    while (true)
    {
        count += 1;
        TempLabel.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
        {
            TempLabel.Text = count.ToString();
        });
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and what fixed the issue.

Comment: Ahh, I thought this was the same code as you said in a comment DIDN'T work. Here, you moved the Task.Delay outside of the Dispatch. Good; that is what Peter said to do. [If the Task.Delay was inside Dispatch, then the loop would attempt to run very very fast, because it has no delay in it. What's inside Dispatch runs separately. The code in that comment would "pile up" many Dispatches, causing slowdown and other problems. Eventually would crash the app.]

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it thread safe. Try and see if this works better for you.

```
Dispatcher.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), () =>
{
    count += 1;
    SpeedLabel.Text = count.ToString();
    return true; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't work! I still have the same problem!

Comment: That is strange. I have tried your code and this and both works for me. Perhaps it is something with your phone or something else that makes the Android think the code is not responding or the OS is interfering in some way.

Comment: Could you see if this works for you when updating the Label in your original code:
Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => SpeedLabel.Text = count.ToString());

Comment: If you meant like this:
        while (true)
        {
            count += 1;
            Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => SpeedLabel.Text = count.ToString());
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
Then it's the same problem.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I think this is not a coding problem but something else.

Comment: 1) With this answer, try a longer time: `1000`. Work better? If so, then in Release mode on a physical device, `100` will probably work well. 2) @PeterWessberg - I'm thinking maybe UI update takes longer than 100 ms on Android (in debug, on emulator), so updates "pile up". But with this answer, I don't think that would happen. Should just increment N times during one update, then the next update goes. [Its a shame there isn't an "update finished" event we could use, to start the next timing cycle. Or at least debug what is happening. I don't like Maui's "hands off" approach.]

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```cs
SpeedLabelUpdate();
```

should show a WARNING in Visual Studio. Right? DO NOT IGNORE that warning.

Warning suggests adding `await`. But you can't. This is a hint that what you are doing is **not reliable**.

Fix it by making an `async` context from which you can `await`:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Code inside here runs AFTER "MainPage()" method returns.
    // Use "Dispatcher.Dispatch", because SpeedLabelUpdate touches UI.
    Dispatcher.Dispatch( async() =>
    {
        await SpeedLabelUpdate();
    }
}
```